# My mic doesn't work on kubuntu

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

Unable to search up a solution to my inability to use my mic, the settings & menus I find illustrated in guides do not appear to be in this version of my OS (kubuntu 19.04).

Have tested the mic on another system, it functions as you would expect & picks up audio from voice & ambient noise. In kubuntu it doesn't pick up sound at all.

The mic is not muted, have looked through all the configurations I can find to no avail, nothing seems wrong with the configurations that I can see.

I just want to record voice & interface sound pickup with various programs such as chrome, discord, skype, phoenix firestorm, etc pretty much the things you would expect from a mic.

[image: Alsa]

[image: Sound Volume Not Muted]

[image: Sound Config from Task Manager]

[image: F4 from Alsamixer]

Thank you for all of your help mook765, but after several more hours of messing with it & a few programs I wanted it to work with, I discovered /facepalm that the front mic jack seems to have failed. I plug into the rear jack & now it works just fine.

Comment: In alsamixer, please hit the `F4`-key to see only input-devices, look for `Capture` and `Input Source`. You can also install QasMixer, a graphical frontend for alsamixer, it's much more convenient (no need to open a terminal and you can use the mouse to move the sliders) and gives you better overview. You can install it with `sudo apt install qasmixer`. I'm not a Kubuntu-user, I use UbuntuStudio, so I can't help you more than that.

Comment: One more thing: what I see in your alsamixer-screenshot are not input-devices, this are boosters (amplifiers) for the microphone. I have them normally muted, but the mic works.

Comment: From the alsa side that should work I would say, you probably need to configure the applications you want to use.